# преобразование даты oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Добрый день!

Oracle 11g, SQL Developer 4.1.3

Пытаюсь вывести возраст записи в виде количества минут прошедших с создания записи. Следующий запрос выводит количество разницу между текущим временем и датой создания:

```
t1.CREATED TIMESTAMP(6)

select localtimestamp - t1.CREATED
from MFSTRANSPORTORDER t1
     left join t2 on t2.ID=t1.TRANSPORTUNIT_ID
     left join t3 on t3.ID=t2.STORAGELOCATION_ID
where t3.NAME is NOT NULL
```

Пример результата: `+00 00:05:57.370523`

Когда пытаюсь применить функцию `to_char(localtimestamp- t1.CREATED,'HH')`, то получаю результат `+000000000 00:05:57.370523`

Как мне всё это с конвертировать в строку, потом число? Или может что-то другое посоветуете?

Хотелось бы всё это разделить на часы, минуты секунды, сложить, поделить на 60 секунд и получить минуты.

Comment: А хранить всё в date?

Comment: не обязательно, мне нужен возраст записи в минутах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Oralce удобно вычитать тип данных date, поэтому преобразуем timestamp в date и потом вычитаем, получаем дробное время в днях, остается умножить на часы/минуты и получим минуты, при желании округлить.

```
select (SYSDATE - cast(t1.CREATED as date))*24*60
  ....
```

Или хранить в БД время сразу в типе данных date, что заметно упрощает последующие запросы.